# mathematica envelope detection data smoothing

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

The following Mathematica code generates a highly oscillatory plot.  I want to plot only  the lower envelope of the plot but do not know how. Any suggestions wouuld be appreciated.

```
tk0 = \[Theta]'[t]*\[Theta]'[t] - \[Theta][t]*\[Theta]''[t]
tk1 = \[Theta]''[t]*\[Theta]''[t] - \[Theta]'[t]*\[Theta]'''[t]
a = tk0/Sqrt[tk1]
f = Sqrt[tk1/tk0]
s =
 NDSolve[{\[Theta]''[t] + \[Theta][t] - 0.167 \[Theta][t]^3 == 
    0.005 Cos[t - 0.5*0.00009*t^2], \[Theta][0] == 0, \[Theta]'[0] == 
    0}, \[Theta], {t, 0, 1000}]

Plot[Evaluate  [f /. s], {t, 0, 1000}, 
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"t", "Frequency"}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15], Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I posted my customary welcome message here again, because you didn't vote and didn't accept any answers in your previous question.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know how fancy you want it to look, but here is a brute force approach which would be good enough for me as a starting point, and can probably be tweaked further:

```
tk0 = \[Theta]'[t]*\[Theta]'[t] - \[Theta][t]*\[Theta]''[t];
tk1 = \[Theta]''[t]*\[Theta]''[t] - \[Theta]'[t]*\[Theta]'''[t];
a = tk0/Sqrt[tk1];
f = Sqrt[tk1/tk0];
s = NDSolve[{\[Theta]''[t] + \[Theta][t] - 0.167 \[Theta][t]^3 == 
 0.005 Cos[t - 0.5*0.00009*t^2], \[Theta][0] == 0, \[Theta]'[0] ==
  0}, \[Theta], {t, 0, 1000}];

plot = Plot[Evaluate[f /. s], {t, 0, 1000}, 
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "Frequency"}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15], Axes -> False];

Clear[ff];
Block[{t, x}, 
  With[{fn = f /. s}, ff[x_?NumericQ] = First[(fn /. t -> x)]]];


localMinPositionsC = 
  Compile[{{pts, _Real, 1}},
    Module[{result = Table[0, {Length[pts]}], i = 1, ctr = 0},
      For[i = 2, i < Length[pts], i++,
        If[pts[[i - 1]] > pts[[i]] && pts[[i + 1]] > pts[[i]],
          result[[++ctr]] = i]];
      Take[result, ctr]]];

(* Note: takes some time *)
points = Cases[
   Reap[Plot[(Sow[{t, #}]; #) &[ff[t]], {t, 0, 1000}, 
      Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
      FrameLabel -> {"t", "Frequency"}, 
      FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15], Axes -> False, 
      PlotPoints -> 50000]][[2, 1]], {_Real, _Real}];

localMins = SortBy[Nest[#[[ localMinPositionsC[#[[All, 2]]]]] &, points, 2], First];

env = ListPlot[localMins, PlotStyle -> {Pink}, Joined -> True];

Show[{plot, env}]
```

What happens is that your oscillatory function has some non-trivial fine structure, and we need a lot of points to resolve it. We collect these points from Plot by Reap - Sow, and then filter out local minima. Because of the fine structure, we need to do it twice. The plot you actually want is stored in "env". As I said, it probably could be tweaked to get a better quality plot if needed.

Edit:

In fact, *much* better plot can be obtained, if we increase the number of PlotPoints from 50000 to 200000, and then repeatedly remove points of local maxima from localMin. Note that it will run slower and require more memory however. Here are the changes:

```
(*Note:takes some time*)
points = Cases[
Reap[Plot[(Sow[{t, #}]; #) &[ff[t]], {t, 0, 1000}, 
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "Frequency"}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15], Axes -> False, 
  PlotPoints -> 200000]][[2, 1]], {_Real, _Real}];

localMins =  SortBy[Nest[#[[localMinPositionsC[#[[All, 2]]]]] &, points, 2], First];

localMaxPositionsC =
  Compile[{{pts, _Real, 1}},
    Module[{result = Table[0, {Length[pts]}], i = 1, ctr = 0},
     For[i = 2, i < Length[pts], i++,
      If[pts[[i - 1]] < pts[[i]] && pts[[i + 1]] < pts[[i]], 
        result[[++ctr]] = i]];
      Take[result, ctr]]];

localMins1 = Nest[Delete[#, List /@ localMaxPositionsC[#[[All, 2]]]] &, localMins, 15];

env = ListPlot[localMins1, PlotStyle -> {Pink}, Joined -> True];

Show[{plot, env}]
```

Edit: here is the plot (done as `GraphicsGrid[{{env}, {Show[{plot, env}]}}]`)

[image]

Comment: I like this answer, but you don't need to go through all that work with `Sow` and `Reap` to get the plot points, because `Plot` will return a `Graphics` object with all the plot points wrapped in a `Line`. Just use `First@Cases[plot, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity]` instead. Also, you can use `Cases` and `Partition` to find local minima very quickly.

Comment: @Pillsy Thanks for the hint with `Plot`. I usually try to avoid relying on the peculiarities of the internal formats when posting code for others, but personally have used this a few times. IMO, using `EvaluationMonitor` in `Plot` would be the cleanest. As for local minima/maxima, yes, you are right, but I was compiling to C (omitted this in the post since not everyone has a C compiler installed), and the version with `Partition` (I used `Position`, not `Cases`) is then about 8-10 times slower (not that this was the major bottleneck here - the bottleneck was in the `Plot` with so many points).

Answer (score 7):

### An Image based solution

I don't claim this one neither robust nor general. But it's quick and fun. It uses Image Transformations to find the edges (possible because the heavy oscillatory character of your function):

Function:

```
envelope[plot_] := Module[{boundary, Pr, rescaled},

  (* "rasterize" the plot, identify the lower edge and isolate pixels*)

  boundary = Transpose@ImageData@Binarize@plot /. {x___, 0, 1, y___} :>
     Join[Array[1 &, Length[{x}]], {0}, Array[1 &, Length[{y}] + 1]];

  (* and now rescale *)

  Pr = PlotRange /. Options[plot, PlotRange];
  rescaled = Position[boundary, 0] /.
    {x_, y_} :> {
      Rescale[x, {1, Dimensions[boundary][[1]]}, Pr[[1]]],
      Rescale[y, {1, Dimensions[boundary][[2]]}, Reverse[Pr[[2]]]]
      };

  (* Finally, return a rescaled and slightly smoothed plot *)

  Return[ListLinePlot@
    Transpose@{( Transpose[rescaled][[1]])[[1 ;; -2]], 
      MovingAverage[Transpose[rescaled][[2]], 2]}]
   ]
```

Testing code:

```
tk0 = phi'[t] phi'[t] - phi[t] phi''[t];
tk1 = phi''[t] phi''[t] - phi'[t] phi'''[t];
a = tk0/Sqrt[tk1];
f = Sqrt[tk1/tk0];
s = NDSolve[{
    phi''[t] + phi[t] - 0.167 phi[t]^3 == 
     0.005 Cos[t - 0.5*0.00009*t^2],
    phi[0] == 0,
    phi'[0] == 0},
   phi, {t, 0, 1000}];
plot = Plot[Evaluate[f /. s], {t, 0, 1000}, Axes -> False];
Show[envelope[plot]]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Fixing a bug in the code above, the results are more accurate:

```
envelope[plot_] := Module[{boundary, Pr, rescaled},

  (*"rasterize" the plot,
  identify the lower edge and isolate pixels*)

  boundary = 
   Transpose@ImageData@Binarize@plot /. {x___, 0, 1, y___} :> 
     Join[Array[1 &, Length[{x}]], {0}, Array[1 &, Length[{y}] + 1]];

  (*and now rescale*)

  Pr = PlotRange /. Options[plot, PlotRange];

  rescaled = Position[boundary, 0] /. {x_, y_} :>
     {Rescale[
       x, {(Min /@ Transpose@Position[boundary, 0])[[1]], (Max /@ 
           Transpose@Position[boundary, 0])[[1]]}, Pr[[1]]], 
      Rescale[y, {(Min /@ 
           Transpose@Position[boundary, 0])[[2]], (Max /@ 
           Transpose@Position[boundary, 0])[[2]]}, Reverse[Pr[[2]]]]};

  (*Finally,return a rescaled and slightly smoothed plot*)
  Return[ListLinePlot[
    Transpose@{(Transpose[rescaled][[1]])[[1 ;; -2]], 
      MovingAverage[Transpose[rescaled][[2]], 2]}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.01]}]]]
```

[image]
.
.

Comment: Belisarius,  Thank you for this clever and useful answer and for your help on this and a previous question.