# How to calculate and plot instantaneous phase in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like a plot of the instantaneous phase difference between a frequency-swept drive and the nonlinear oscillator it is driving.  x[t] below is the instantaneous displacement of the oscillator and plotx provides a plot.

Thanks,
Carey

```
s =
 NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] - 0.167 x[t]^3 == 
    0.005 Cos[t - 0.5*0.0000652*t^2], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, 
  x, {t, 0, 3000}, MaxSteps -> 35000]

plotx = Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. s], {t, 0, 3000}, PlotPoints -> 10000, 
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, FrameLabel -> {"t", "x"}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15], PlotLabel -> "(a)", 
  Axes -> False]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think that some of the code given to you in [previous answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667323/mathematica-envelope-detection-data-smoothing/4668972#4668972) could be used to find the turning points and thus estimate the phase of the oscillator.

Comment: I guess you could use a less "physics" jargon, to give the non-physicists Mma users an opportunity to understand your problem. Show what is the stimulus and what is the response clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Response, take 2)

You can get a reasonable approximation of the phase with

```
f[tt_?NumericQ] := -(ArcTan @@ ({x[t], x'[t]}/
    Sqrt[x[t]^2 + x'[t]^2]) /. s[[1]]) /. t -> tt
```

Here are some plots. First we show the driving term and the result together. It indicates they are a bit out of phase.

```
plotx2 = Plot[
  Evaluate[{x[t], Cos[t - 0.5*0.0000652*t^2]/5} /. s], {t, 0, 100}, 
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, FrameLabel -> {"t", "x"}]
```

[image]

Now we show the two phases together. I plot over a slightly different range this time.

```
phaseangles = 
 Plot[{f[t], Mod[t - 0.5*0.0000652*t^2, 2*Pi, -Pi]}, {t, 100, 120}, 
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, FrameLabel -> {"t", "x"}]
```

[image]

Last we show the phase differences.

```
phasediffs = 
 Plot[{f[t] - Mod[t - 0.5*0.0000652*t^2, 2*Pi, -Pi]}, {t, 100, 120}, 
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, FrameLabel -> {"t", "x"}]
```

[image]

Possibly I'm off by something additive (those Mod[] terms get bothersome), but this should give an idea of how one might proceed.

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Comment: Thank you Daniel for the very helpful details.

Comment: Hi Daniel,  Your suggestion worked well.  A question regarding your method of approximating phase:  f[tt_?NumericQ] := -(ArcTan @@ ({x[t], x'[t]}/ Sqrt[x[t]^2 + x'[t]^2]) /. s[[1]]) /. t -> tt.
I understand phase can be approximated as arctan (quadrature signal/in-phase signal).  Why can't that be approximated simply as arctan (x'[t]/x[t])) instead of arctan((x'[t]/ Sqrt[x[t]^2 + x'[t]^2]))/x[t]), i.e., why is x'[t] divided by the hypoteneuse of the signal triangle (x=adjacent side, x'=opposite side) giving the cos of the phase angle in the numerator of the arctan argument? Thanks , Carey

Comment: @Cary I think that denominator was a holdover from some earlier attempt, possibly to forestall division by zero problems. From what I can tell in a quick test, it seems to be unnecessary for the current code in question. I should add that if it were in 1-arg ArcTan it would mess up the result. In the 2-arg variant it effectively cancels with itself, so no harm done.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look very closely at the [method of averaging](http://www.google.com/search?q=averaged+equations&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=method+of+averaging&cp=0&qe=bWV0aG9kIG9mIGF2ZXJhZ2luZw&qesig=ZoymwQ6QqSz76Msp5Y_tMA&pkc=AFgZ2tnSa-IGj5SWll5f5G5YTC5lCq2kRrYxDuQjjhi3LCK3WJ_QxwXNcqIIfU22EtDLkjOxf67xu6pHGZSNirVf1Yw6iJaRYg&pf=p&sclient=psy&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3Aofficial&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=method+of+averaging&pbx=1&fp=73f7402448ded2e2&bs=1).  In [Strogatz's implementation](http://books.google.com/books?id=FIYHiBLWCJMC&pg=PA239&lpg=PA239&dq=strogatz+method+of+averaging&source=bl&ots=lxcG7oPXXG&sig=Yx88DNugwqTTQoKxlL5VnnebJ5c&hl=en&ei=qb1aTZXfHIGC8gbD5eGYDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false), both the average envelope and phase of a nonlinear oscillator are found.  Since you are looking for something a little bit beyond the first order, I'd consider looking at this [paper](http://oai.dtic.mil/oai/oai?verb=getRecord&metadataPrefix=html&identifier=ADA258990) from the Air Force Academy.

Comment: Hi rcollyer,  Thank you for the link to the paper on averaging.

Comment: @Carey, you're welcome. Out of curiosity, what are you working on?

Comment: @rcollyer, I'm doing doctoral research on resonantly forced nonlinear oscillators.

Comment: @Carey, I had a class using Strogatz's book, and some of the stuff was very interesting.

Comment: @rcollyer, My course in nonlinear dynamics also used Strogatz's book. It is an excellent text but only only briefly discusses forced (non-autonomous) systems like the ones I am studying.  Mathematica is unsurpassed for symbolic computation but I am finding R to be very nice for everything else, especially since it now has good ODE solvers and time series packages.

Comment: @Carey, how did you make out with those papers?  Were they useful?